# C# BadImageFormatException on only one PC?

Tags: c#

I'm seeing an issue between two PCs I regularly work on with a bunch of C# solutions. On one PC, I can start up my ASP.NET Core projects, run, test, and debug them without issue.

On the other PC, I keep getting this issue:

> System.BadImageFormatException : Could not load file or assembly 'System.IO.Pipelines, Version=4.0.2.2, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'. Format of the executable (.exe) or library (.dll) is invalid.

It's only in these solutions too. If I create a new ASP.NET Core project on the problematic PC, it runs without issue as far as I can tell.

It seems to happen regardless of project or branch of code I'm working on. Has anyone seen anything like this before or have suggestions for things to try and fix?

Comment: not sure, but may be dll version mismatch or missing! make sure that particular dll exist on the machine.

Comment: BadImageFormatException, usually come if running 64 bit on 32 bit.